# Propagation of an error in the LMO invariant? (Revision: I don't think LMO is wrong!)

Tags: knot-theory, gt.geometric-topology

**Edit:** I think LMO is correct. Massuyeau has a nice explanation [here.](http://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/a-problem-with-lmo/)
**Edit:** Renaud Gauthier has retracted the claim of an error in the foundations of the LMO construction, and has withdrawn both preprints from arXiv.

Original post follows:

---

In two papers posted to the arXiv in the past few days, Renaud Gauthier claims to have discovered an error in the definition of the framed Kontsevich integral used in the construction of the LMO invariant. I have no reason to doubt him. I looked at these papers some years back and recall that something funny was going on with the normalization under handle-slides. I got the wrong multiple of the normalization factor $\nu$, just as Gauthier does. Gauthier fixes the normalization so that it works, but then remarks that subsequent results depending on this construction need to be carefully checked.

My question is whether anyone knows of results that use the fine details of the definition of the framed Kontsevich integral (or LMO invariant or Aarhus integral) which are now thrown into doubt because of this error.

**Edit:** Here are links to the papers.

[On the foundations of the LMO invariant](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2422)

[On the LMO Invariant, the Wheeling Theorem, and the Aarhus Integral](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2559)

**Edit 2:**
Moskovich has started a blog post on this. Thanks to Ryan Budney for pointing this out.

[A problem with LMO?](http://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/a-problem-with-lmo/)

Comment: Add link to the arXiv papers?

Comment: I just came here for a little explanation of the LMO invariant. I have no idea what it is. Could you tell me a little something about it. I know nothing of topology and or knot theory.

Comment: I was supposed to add a question mark.

Comment: I don't this post is the place for an exposition of the LMO invariant. Maybe ask as a separate question if you want to know (or read the papers cited the links above!)?

Comment: Daniel Moskovich just started a blog post about your very question, Jim. http://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/a-problem-with-lmo/

Comment: Ohtsuki has a delightful book called "Quantum invariants: a study of knots, 3-manifolds, and their sets" which contains an exposition of the LMO invariant and is partially available on google books.  I haven't actually read the LMO section of the book. I was reading a different part in order to fix a minor error in the normalization of the ribbon element for the unrestricted quantum group elsewhere in the literature (Ohtsuki had it right in that case).


Comment: I believe that Gauthier's claim is refuted by Gwenael Massuyeau's comment: http://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/a-problem-with-lmo/

Comment: Interestingly, Gauthier has just posted a new version of his paper, and doesn't appear to be retracting his main claim.

Comment: In particular, he doesn't address address Massuyeau's comment at all. (Nor does he address an innaccuracy noticed by Dylan Thurston.)  

Comment: I am not expert in the details of all of this, but I have noticed one thing as a bystander: Not enough direct communication between Gauthier and the people whose work he criticizes or who criticize his work. His advisor is Soibelman, who is highly respected. Maybe he can help move the debate to a more efficient and more private forum.  Because, so far the debate has only been interesting for negative reasons.

Comment: Greg, some people have communicated with Gauthier, but I certainly agree that this mathoverflow post is not generating anything productive anymore.

Comment: @Jim - Let me suggest accepting Dror's answer as provisionally correct.  Also, my point was not that this MathOverflow posting was bad; actually it's fine.  Rather, I meant to say that Gauthier shared his thoughts in completely the wrong way.

Comment: Both preprints have been withdrawn from arXiv. I must say that I am very impressed with Gauthier- as soon as it became clear that there was an error, he acknowledged it and withdrew his preprints.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Having been a part of the LMO story from its beginning, and having read and checked all relevant papers carefully at the time, and having taken part in many cross-checks that the LMO invariant passed (normalization-compatibility with Reshetikhin-Turaev, various explicit computations), and having consulted on email with my collaborators at the time, and having superficially read through Gauthier, my informed guess is that in this particular case of inconsistency the first place to look for a problem is in Gauthier, not in LMO.